# Please suggest a good Monitoring and Alerting tool for applications hosted in cloud

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am looking for a monitoring and alerting tool for my application hosted in cloud. My application is hosted across multiple servers and I want to monitor all these servers. I am interested in monitoring the following:

**1. Service monitoring:**

- Check if the service is up. This requires

  - try siging-up a new user
  - log-in to the application with given username/password and perform certain steps like search etc.
- Monitoring QoS. How much time is it taking for searches and some other opertions

**2. resource monitoring**
Monitoring the following parameters in each server:

- CPU utilization
- load average
- Memory usage
- Disk usage
- IOPS

**3. process  monitoring**

Monitor if a set of processes are running or not. If not running try restarting them.
Ex: php-fpm, my application binaries, mysql, nginx, smtp etc.

**4. Monitoring log files**

- Error logs of my application
- mysql error log
- MySQL slow query log
  etc.

Also I should be able to extend its usage by executing shell commands or writing my own shell scripts.

I should be able to set alert if any monitored item is found problematic. I should be able to get alert through

- email
- Mobile SMS

The Monitoring system should maintain history for the period I want. So that after receiving the alert I should be able to log-in to the 
system and view past data (say past 2 weeks) and investigate problems.

**Most important:**

The tool should have a very good way of managing its own configuration.

- The configuration should not be scattered at multiple places. All configuration should be stored in a centralized place. In future say, path of a monitored log file has changed. I would like to search and replace all occurrences of that file in my configuration.
- I should be able to version control my configurations.
- Instead of going to the web interface and setting configuration manually, I would like set up a script which automatically loads all the configurations and start monitoring.

I am exploring Zabbix but don't see a satisfactory way of configuration management. Should I try Nagios? Any other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nagios is one of the standard ways of monitoring and can support all the use cases you brought up (plus, plugins have probably already been written for all of them).

Answer (score 1):

2 newer cloud type monitoring solutions that may be of interested to you are http://logicmonitor.com/ and http://copperegg.com/.

LogicMonitor has many of your requirements out of the box as it has a bit of customization for your own alerting.

CopperEgg / RevealCloud is more base system level monitoring (CPU, memory, disk, and network throughput). It has a nice polished interface that is much more straightforward than LogicMonitor. But that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering you've tagged this with Zabbix, I assume you're considering this as an option.

We use Zabbix to monitor the Amazon EC2 instances as well as instances in our private openstack cloud. It's as simple as "apt-get install zabbix-agent" really.

Zabbix is especially useful in the case of monitoring our openstack private cloud. We have the server scan an ip-range and automatically set up checks, alerts, etc, based solely on the hostname of the machine found.